# Qt splitter with empty widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a small window where inside is horizontal QSplitter, on one side there is control widget (labels, buttons, list widget etc), on another side there is empty widget (where stuff will be painted).
But because of empty widget splitter resizes control widget to maximum and view widget to minimum. I tried to set horizontal size policy to "Minimum" for control widget and to "Expanding" for view widget and layouts, that didn't helped.
What would be right (or easiest) way to set size for controll widget to be as small as possible and view widget expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was enough to set Horizontal Stretch to factor 2 for view widget size policy.